# How to create differently sized group bar plot?

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, matlab-figure

I would like to make a bar plot in Matlab with differently sized groups, i.e. the groups can have a variable number of bars. Assume the following data with 4 groups:

```
a = [1]; 
b = [3 5];
c = [4 6 7];
d = [3 6 7 9];
```

Of course I could just padd with zeros but then the group labels at the bottom are not centered below the bars (due to the zero height bars).

How could this be resolved?

Comment: Interesting question. I guess it is not easily possible. You could maybe look into how Matlab does it themselves and then try to modify their code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

- u can use zeros() function for create a zeros matrix with same size, then u can change the elements an all vectors will be same size.

Comment: That does not solve the problem because then for my group "a" above I have 3 zero height bars and the label of the group is not placed below the single bar.